# Office Web Apps 2013 on different domain

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps

Does anybody know if it's possible to connect a SharePoint 2013 farm to an Office Web Apps farm that's on a separate domain?

I tried to set it up using the steps documented in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx, and did not get any error message from PowerShell. But when I actually go to open a document in the browser, I get the following message:

> "Sorry, there was a problem and we can't open this document. If this
>   happens again, try opening the document in Microsoft Word."

I also see the following correlated exceptions in the ULS:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service,
>   'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc'
>   could not be activated.
>
> WOPIFrame - Unhandled exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service,
>   'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc'
>   could not be activated.

Comment: is the web apps url http or https?